# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined | Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, syntax-error

I am using Node express and mongodb. I am trying to be able to loop through all the relevant properties for a show page. My code is

```
Desktop.find({}, function(err, allDesktop) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
              console.log(allDesktop); // #1
                res.locals.desktops = allDesktop; // Set the data in locals
            }
        });
        console.log("res.locals.desktops:  ", res.locals.desktops); //#2
```

That code is part of the route, the #1 `console.log` logs out all the results correct. But `console.log` #2 returns `undefined`. Why is this? I know I have set it similar in other spots in the exact same route but instead to `res.locals.laptops`

What am I missing here?

Comment: `Desktop.find` is synchronous function, you can't use it result immediately after the call. The result is available in callback, because of that the first call of `console.log` prints the correct data, but second `undefined`.

Comment: `Desktop.find()` is executing but then it moves on to your `console.log()` before the callback is executed upon the db returning results - you are trying to print the result before it has been returned. Move your `console.log()` inside the callback.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the [Event Loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#what-is-the-event-loop). In short, `Desktop.find()` will execute, but you don't know *when* it will finish.

That's where your callback comes into play: `function(err, allDesktop) {}`. The callback is called when `Desktop.find()` finishes execution.

So the code is evaluated top to bottom which results in `res.locals.desktops` to be `undefined`. Something like this should solve your issue:

```
Desktop.find({}).exec()
    .then(allDesktop => {
        res.locals.desktops = allDesktop
        return Promise.resolve()
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(res.locals.desktops)
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

`.exec()` returns a `MongooseThenable` which is essentially a `Promise`.

Comment: You have a typo in your assignment `allDesktops` should be `allDesktop`

Comment: Also there is no need to convert to promises, you can do the exact same thing using the original example and a callback

Comment: @doublesharp What? `allDesktop` is the exact same in all places it exists. there is `desktops` on the `res.local` but never `allDesktops`

Comment: @JoshKirby The comment doublesharp made about `allDesktops` refers to line 3 of the code posted in this answer, which is inconsistent with line 2.

Comment: @skirtle Oh, I looked too quick I guess, I thought he was in reply to me.